# create an DAO Access file in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2010, dao

I am unable to create a file using following commands, could anyone help me in this regard. The error it says is invalid argument.
I got office 2010.

My ref is :MS office 14.0 ACCESS DATABASE OBJECT LIBRARY

```
Sub DBcreate()

Dim DB As DAO.Database
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset


Set DB = DAO.Workspaces(0).CreateDatabase("D:\tblImport11.accdb",    DB_LANG_GENERAL)
      DB.Close

    'Set RS = Nothing
    Set DB = Nothing
End Sub
```

i also tried:

```
Set DB = DBEngine.CreateDatabase("D:\tblImport11.accdb", DB_LANG_GENERAL)
```

This also gives same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DB_LANG_GENERAL` is the wrong parameter. Use:

```
Set DB = DBEngine.CreateDatabase("D:\tblImport11.accdb", dbLangGeneral)
```